# There are 10 types 0f pe0ple 1n the w0rld

Tags: word, cipher, crosswords

<sub>Th1s puzzle 1s part 0f the [Monthly Topic Challenge #4: Cross-*non*-words](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7406/)</sub>

---

C0mplete the cr0ssw0rd and f1nd the h1dden themat1c e1ght-character s0lut10n w0rd.

[image: Crossword grid]

> **Acr0ss:**
> 7. Pref1x mean1ng 'just a few' 0r 'scanty' (e.g. _____z00sperm1a - l0w sperm c0unt) (5)
> 8. Brand 0f st0ck cubes (3)
> 9. _____ G1nk0, the f1rst l1censed female phys1c1an pract1c1ng Western med1c1ne 1n Japan (5)
> 11. Ne1ghb0urh00d 0f L0nd0n 0r New Y0rk? (4)
> 12. French w0rd, mean1ng 'Here' (3)
> 13. Un1lever's largest detergent brand, als0 kn0wn as Pers1l, Sk1p, and Surf Excel (3)
> 14. Generat10n 1 R0ck/Gr0und-type P0kém0n (4)
> 15. Ann0 ______, "1n the year 0f the L0rd" (6)
> 17. ___Mabuse, TV talent sh0w judge, presenter, and pr0fess10nal dancer (3)
> 18. ______ Strauss, c0-0wner 0f Macy's department st0re wh0 d1ed 0n the T1tan1c (6)
> 20. 0ne-p1ece beach garment equ1valent t0 the l0wer half 0f a b1k1n1 (8)
> 23. F0rt1f1ed w1nes made 1n Jerez and M0nt1lla-M0r1les, pr0duced by 0x1dat1ve ag1ng (8)
> 26. Der0gat0ry term f0r a pers0n w1th str0ng v1ews ab0ut g0vernment (8)
> 29. Rac1el G0nzales ________, d0uble s1lver medall1st 1n the T46 class at the 2012 Summer Paralymp1cs (8)
> 31. Fam1ly 0f ser1f typefaces des1gned by G1ambatt1sta ______ 1n the late e1ghteenth century (6)
> 34. ___ Karl0v1ć, Cr0at1an tenn1s player, f0rmer w0rld rec0rd h0lder f0r fastest serve and m0st career aces (3)
> 35. 21-t1me w1nners 0f the Cypr10t F1rst D1v1s10n (f00tball) (6)
> 37. Large desert 1n East As1a, the s1xth largest 1n the w0rld (4)
> 39. ___ J1ma, Japanese 1sland, s1te 0f 1c0n1c WW11 flag-ra1s1ng ph0t0graph (3)
> 40. ___ Energy, a Br1t1sh gas and electr1c1ty suppl1er (3)
> 41. R0man p0et, auth0r 0f *The Metam0rph0ses* (4)
> 42. D1v0ck _____, Belg1an f00tballer, g0alsc0rer 1n the 2019 UEFA Champ10ns League f1nal (5)
> 43. Br0ad sash w0rn r0und the wa1st 0f a Japanese k1m0n0 (3)
> 44. Hardw00d tree 0f West Afr1ca, 0f the genus *M1l1c1a* (5)
>
> **D0wn:**
> 1. Eleventh c0dew0rd 1n the NAT0 ph0net1c alphabet (4)
> 2. Fab10 ______, f0rmer Chelsea and L1verp00l f00tballer, currently play1ng f0r Fat1h Karagümrük (6)
> 3. J0hn W1ll1am ________, auth0r 0f *The Vampyre* (1819) (8)
> 4. S1te 0f a f1erce battle 1n September 1812 dur1ng Nap0le0n's 1nvas10n 0f Russ1a (8)
> 5. Cap1tal c1ty 0f C0m0r0s (6)
> 6. Fred and W1lma Fl1ntst0ne's pet (4)
> 7. Ferd1nand _____, Camer00n1an d1pl0mat and Cha1rman 0f UN1CEF, 1977-78 (5)
> 10. 1tal1an w0rd, mean1ng 'sheep' (5)
> 16. "1f y0u ask me..." (3, 1n1ts)
> 19. Heard tw1ce at a wedd1ng? (1,2)
> 21. Y0k0 ___, Japanese art1st, s1nger, s0ngwr1ter, and peace act1v1st (3)
> 22. "__ _ was an astr0naut" - 0pen1ng l1ne 0f Sam Ryder's 2022 Eur0v1s10n h1t, *Spaceman* (2,1)
> 24. French w0rd 0f agreement (3)
> 25. Jama1can mus1c art1st beh1nd 2010s h1t, *Cheerleader* (3)
> 27. *Sh0uld 1 Stay 0r Sh0uld _ __*, 1982 h1t f0r The Clash (1,2)
> 28. Kukr1 snake genus (8)
> 29. (0f a dr1nk) C0nta1n1ng essent1al salts and m1nerals 1n the same c0ncentrat10n as 1n the b0dy (8)
> 30. "Aha! ___! A track 1n the sn0w!" (*The Gruffal0's Ch1ld*) (3)
> 32. Anth0ny _____, b0x1ng br0nze medall1st at the 2012 Summer 0lymp1cs (5)
> 33. Swell1ng 0r 1nflammat10n 1n the c0l0ured r1ng ar0und the pup1l 0f the eye (6)
> 35. Eth10p1an state, h0me t0 the cap1tal, Add1s Ababa (6)
> 36. "Hell0. My name 1s _____ M0nt0ya. Y0u k1lled my father. Prepare t0 d1e." (*The Pr1ncess Br1de*) (5)
> 38. L0ng-legged wad1ng b1rd (4)
> 41. W00dw1nd 1nstrument (4)

Comment: Ok, I might finally start doing crosswords... but how do you like *import* this crossword to solve it?

Comment: @Stevo What I usually do is copy-paste the image into Word, then enter letters into an overlaid text box using a monospaced font, resizing the font and grid to get a 1-1 match with letters in boxes. Others copy-paste into something like MS Paint and freehand it. Still others print it off and enter with pen like a newspaper crossword. Lots of choices :)

Comment: thanks! Okay, time to scrap my excel...

Comment: And as for me – Inkscape is my trusty friend.

Comment: As a type 10 kind op person I was shocked when reading about world war three in clue 39...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We solve the crossword as follows:

> [image]
>  Eight rows each have eight 0s and 1s spelling out a binary ASCII codepoint. The corresponding characters read out **B1n0m1al (BINOMIAL)**.

Comment: Great job, well found :) And a tip for future contributors to this month's MTC: You'll note here that all of the 'non-letters' appear in a regular grid pattern, at every intersection of words - this is one way (but far from being the only one) to meet the challenge's criterion of no word appearing spelled out in full...